# Infinite HTML input?

Tags: html, css, text, scroll

I have an input: `<input type="text">`. But if I type something longer than the length, it scrolls left. Obviously, I expected this, but I'm stuck trying to prevent that. I tried:

```
input {
    width: auto;
}
```

but that doesn't work. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: So, you want the input to expand as the user types?

Comment: @Rojo Yes, pretty much.

Comment: I think that would be a bit disturbing as a client. Why not use `textarea` and just let line breaks be created?

Comment: @Rojo That wouldn't work, because the input is supposed to update a `<p>` tag when you click enter. It gets replaced with the input, so if there were line breaks and then there aren't anymore it would look strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an `input`, you can use `span`:

```html
<span role="textbox" contenteditable>Type here!</span>
```

Comment: Would `.select()` work on it? When I tried it it gave me an error.

Comment: @illogicalapple `.select()` is specfically for `input` elements

Comment: Is there another way to do that then?

Comment: [This CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/auto-growing-inputs-textareas/) blog has a working example. Note that it uses SCSS. There is a JS solution before it, but it seems a bit buggy.

Comment: I looked for a while, and apparently [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/987376/15434173) works. Thanks for the help!